# xib/uibuttons added as ViewController Subview?

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, xib, subview

I have a viewcontroller in a storyboard. Programmatically I am adding a xib as a subview to this viewController/view using "loadLibNamed".

The xib only has uibuttons. Currently I have the xib assigned as a separate uiview subclass. How can I have the view controller responding to uibutton events as if the uibuttons were wired directly to the view controller? That is, I'd effectively like to have all the IBAction code living in the corresponding viewcontroller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use message forwarding from your subclass, but that would be complex.

It might be easiest if you have your XIBbelong to your view controller. Set up the XIB with your view controller as file's owner, and with the outlets and IBActions connected as normal. Then when you load it, it will hook up the outlets and actions as normal.

Comment: Started with a new xib and now I can both set the class to my view controller and connect the buttons to the file owner. This should have me on my way...